# How to click on the first result on google using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on the first result on the google result. Here is my code 
where I am entering chennai craiglist which is read from csv file. So I am sure the first link that come in the organic result will be chennai.craiglist.org. But I am quiet not sure about how to do this.

```
from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
    from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
    import unittest, time, re

    class Browse(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    self.base_url = "http://google.com/"

    filename = 'test.csv'
    line_number = 1
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        mycsv = csv.reader(f)
        mycsv = list(mycsv)
        self.cityname=mycsv[line_number][0]
        self.username=mycsv[line_number][1]
        self.password=mycsv[line_number][2]
        self.verificationErrors = []

def test_browse(self):
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get(self.base_url + "/")
    driver.find_element_by_id("gbqfq").send_keys(self.cityname)
```

I wanna know what should come after this line?

UPDATE

right now I am giving like

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[@id='rso']//div//h3/a")[:1].click()
```

I am not sure if it will work or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `xpath` you have chosen is 'ok' but probably not the best.

```
result = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ol[@id="rso"]/li")[0] //make a list of results and get the first one
result.find_element_by_xpath("./div/h3/a").click() //click its href
```

Comment: +1 for showing, that you can also search in already initialized webelement

Answer (score 3):

This works great with google results.

```
results = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="r"]/a/h3')  # finds webresults
results[0].click(). # clicks the first one
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been using `driver.find_element_by_tag_name("cite").click()` in python3 which has worked for me. However if you just want the link to the top search result it would be faster to use the requests and BeautifulSoup libraries as shown below

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'http://www.google.com/search?q=something'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
print(soup.find('cite').text)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. "iUh30" is class name of the first google search result irrespective of the keyword searched.
2. .text will fetch url pointed by locator(class_name)
3. driver.get() will navigate to the url

`driver.get(driver.find_element_by_class_name("iUh30").text)`

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.